# This declaration has no storage class or type specifier when Initializing static member

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, static

this is my code.

> lib.hpp

```
class MainMenuDriver {
public:
    static LiquidCrystal lcd;
    static std::vector<std::string> menu_items;
    static std::stack<std::string>  menu_stack;
    static std::stack<std::string>  temp_stack;
    // ...
```

> main.cpp

```
#include "lib.hpp"

MainMenuDriver::lcd = LiquidCrystal(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7); // Error
// ...
```

Assume `LiquidCrystal` actually exists, as you can see here, I want to seperate the Blueprint and Operation into two different parts. I already know you can initialize `lcd` in `MainMenuDriver`'s constructor but **I want to call this constructor in a static way, meaning i do not want to create an instance of MainMenuDriver.**

Thank you all  in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to also specify the type when initializing the static data member `lcd` as shown below. Use

```
LiquidCrystal MainMenuDriver::lcd = LiquidCrystal(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```